# Content overlapping div

Tags: css, html, overlapping

I'm having issues with overlapping contents. When I try this code for the HTML the text within content_left overlaps the entire area i want it to contain. When I change height to auto, it does not solve the problem.. Contents overlap to the right and the bottom is cut off.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 20px auto auto auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(wrapper.png);
}

.content_left {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 30px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
    </div>

    <div id="header_right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content_left">
    hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh
    hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh
    hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh hfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfhhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhfhffhfh
  </div>

  <div class="content_right">
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Example [jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6acE/)

Comment: you will need to provide the CSS for the rest of the elements... a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiffle.net) would be best

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli http://jsfiddle.net/L6acE/

Answer (score 6):

Seeing the full fiddle, the comments i can make are

- remove the `height:700px;` from the `#wrapper`
- add `overflow:hidden` on the `#wrapper`
- add `word-wrap: break-word;` on the `.content_left`
  (*this will enable word-breaking since your text is too long to fit in a single line..*)

The result can bee seen at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/L6acE/1/

---

Support for this feature can be seen at http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Answer (score 5):

its because there is no space in string(word) try

```
 .content_left{overflow:hidden;}
```

and i dont think any valid string(word) as long as yours