# Footer content overlapping wrapper div

Tags: css, html, overlapping

I have a footer content that is overlapping the wrapper div in my css and html, when I changed height to auto it didnt work.
below is an example of the page I'm working on.

**Wrapper CSS**

```
#wrapper {
width: 1030px;
height: 600px;
margin: 20px auto auto auto;
padding: 0;
background: url(wrapper.png);
}
```

**Footer CSS**

```
.footer{
width: 1000px;
padding: 60px 0 0 30px;
height: auto;
float: right;
clear: both;
background: url(footer_bg.gif) no-repeat top right;
text-align: center;

}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6acE/)

Comment: How is this question different from the last question you asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432241/content-overlapping-div?

Comment: Please compare both questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your floats in the .content_left and content_right columns and remove the height associated with your #wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6acE/3/

There's a few different methods for clearing floats.  I went with a real simple method of just adding a `<div style="clear:both;">` after both columns as discussed here:

http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

But I'd generally use a clearfix method discussed here:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

I also added in some `word-wrap:break-word` CSS for your left column to wrap all your dummy content.